# Updating a large (280M rows) table with anonymised data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

We have a production database which is being migrated to a new environment, and the customer requires data in certain columns and certain tables to be anonymised while the project is in the development phase.

The supplier has provided a script which replaces the data - for example:

```
UPDATE ThisTable SET Description = 'Anonymised ' + TableKey
```

Now the problem is that several of the tables have millions of rows. The biggest is 284,000,000 rows.

The above statement will, of course, never work for such a table due to  Locks, TempDb and row versions, log files, etc. etc.

I have a script which I've used before which in essence does the following:

**Current version of how i am doing it:**
1. Creates a temp table of the source table's PK (and creates an index on the PK).
2. Selects top n PKs from the temp table and processes the appropriate rows in source table.
3. Deletes the top n PKs from the temp table
4. Repeats from step 2

This works well - it gives reasonable performance (and does some metrics to be able to predict end time). However, running it on the large table gives a predicted run time of 4 days!

Other measures I've taken are to put the database in simple recovery mode.

We have exclusive access to the server, and can 'do what we want' with it.

The core problem is that we're talking large numbers of rows. One thought is BCP OUT to text file(s), process offline, and BCP in. However, then we're still into processing a text file with 284,000,000 lines!

**ASK:**
So - any other thoughts on how to achieve the above? Am I missing a 'simple' way to do this?

Comment: Can you please provide some sample of how you are going to anonymise data ?

Comment: run in batches.....

Comment: What actually happens if you try to update it all at once?   I don't see why splitting it up will make it quicker.  I once used row_number based on primary key, then wrote out the key for every ten-thousandth record, found by using row_number % 10000 = 0, then I could go through the file deleting keys 10,000 at a time.

Comment: Updating all at once using the simple sql above results in TempDb filing up disk space as it tries to hold all the RowVersions. Maybe increasing TempDb size and associated disk space would work. Bearing in mind that the update failed about 4.5 hours after the query was run.

Comment: My solution is already to run it in batches. This avoids massive transactions. The problem then is purely the time taken to process the updates.

Comment: all I can think of to try is splitting the batches between processes, for example marking ranges in a temp table as a,b,c,d etc - then having some number of concurrent processing - saying that, you're probably already thinking that it will hit some bottle neck, and that it's optimistic to think that having 10 processes will be 10 times quicker - by the time you've written and investigated optimisation - it would probably have finished

Comment: This is the best approach I am aware of

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60789/what-are-the-most-effective-techniques-to-reduce-sql-server-disk-space-use-when

It isn't very different to what you are doing.  Removing any non-clustered indexes and adding them back again afterwards may help.

Comment: @JonathanShields Thanks for the link - quite useful. Not sure whether dropping the non-clustered indexes will make much difference if I'm not upating indexed columns. Setting the transaction isolation level hadn't occurred to me - that might help. As we're all saying - batching is the way to go after that (and that's what I'm doing).

Comment: @JamesLavery is it possible to change the recovery model if so then convert the update to select * into with change ,this is faster no tempdb spill, no big log growth and much faster. renaming the table and recreating the indexes and constraints with bulk logged recovery model is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 Crate same table structure in with name ie tablename+temp

Step 2 Now do insert into  tablename+temp from select from tablename.

ie  insert into  tablenametemp
       select colunns   'Anonymised ' + TableKey as Description  from tablename.

Step 3 Rename tablename to tablename1 and tablename+temp to tablename

Step 4   drop tablename1 (after verification)

Note if you have constrain create do rename them too.

Comment: surely that will do all, and more work on top, that the update would do alone.  It would avoid record locks perhaps, but I thought the DB was for him to do what he wants with - so I don't understand his record lock problem

Comment: I agree with @AndrewDeighton - this does what we could do already on the source table. I have no problems with locking the table for other users - we've got exclusive access to the database. Regarding the 'lock problem' - I'm probably incorrect on that (was thinking back to older days). However, we _would_ have a problem with the simplistic update with TempDb filling up with RowVersions.